# How to fail test if result is not found in a loop c#

Tags: c#, loops, selenium, testing

I have a for loop in which I look for attributes that match what I have typed in as a parameter. It passes when it is found but when it isn't found, it keeps looping through. I need a way in which to get the test to fail if it isn't found.

```
foreach (IWebElement link in links)
{
    string text = link.GetAttribute("alt");
    if (text == transportMode)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(text, transportMode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely you can just `break` or `throw` when the condition is not met?

Comment: Does *every* member of the set need to match, or just one?

Comment: You're skipping the assertion if the values aren't equal with your `if` clause.  Don't test and then assert, just assert.

Answer (score 2):

No need to assert inside the loop (because your `if` statement checks exactly the same). Just jump out of the test if you found it. Otherwise fail at the end of the test:

```
foreach (IWebElement link in links)
{
    string text = link.GetAttribute("alt");
    if (text == transportMode)
    {
        return;
    }
}
Assert.Fail("not found");
```

You may want to think of a more clever message than I used.

Comment: Thank you. That's fixed my problem.

Comment: The OP used curly braces with the if statement. Please don't encourage by way of example not using them.

Comment: @jibbs Ok, I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned whether this is NUnit or MSTest, but in both cases

```
Assert.Fail("Error message");
```

fails the test

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple using LINQ:

```
Assert.IsTrue(links.Select(l => l.GetAttribute("alt")).Contains(transportMode));
```